# Android Facebook Login Sdk: getActivity().getCallingActivity() returns null from their LoginFragment.class

Tags: android, facebook-login, android-facebook

I'm using the facebook-sdk for the facebook login button. This the facebook library I'm using:

```
implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

This is the crash raised by Firebase Crashlytics:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqArL.png

On this devices:

- Galaxy S7 not rooted Android 7.0
- Huawei Honor 9(STF-L09) not rooted Android 8.0

I check the code to know what is the Facebook library doing but I didn't find anything that I can do from my code to solve it. This is the method that raised the crash(LoginFragment.java line 68):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        loginClient = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(SAVED_LOGIN_CLIENT);
        loginClient.setFragment(this);
    } else {
        loginClient = new LoginClient(this);
    }

    callingPackage = getActivity().getCallingActivity().getPackageName();
    request = (LoginClient.Request)
            getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_REQUEST);

    loginClient.setOnCompletedListener(new LoginClient.OnCompletedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(LoginClient.Result outcome) {
            onLoginClientCompleted(outcome);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the getCallingActivity method that returns null from android.app.Activity.java

```
public ComponentName getCallingActivity() {
        try {
            return ActivityManager.getService().getCallingActivity(mToken);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            return null;
        }
}
```

I cannot reproduce the error with the testing devices at the office so I only have the Crashlytics report to solve it. I 'm clueless because it seems to work for most of the devices

Any help would be amazing, thanks in advance